# Erro 400 ao enviar um Array Buffer JavaScript para uma Action C#

Tags: javascript, c#

Após receber um arquivo CSV e fazer a leitura dele com o FileReader do JS, preciso enviar o retorno dessa leitura para uma Action de um Controller C#. Porém ao enviar, recebo um erro 400. Gostaria de saber uma forma de enviar esses dados para o back-end e sanar esse erro. Segue abaixo os códigos :

**Função JS para ler o CSV.**

```
function lerCSV() {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {

        var resultado = reader.result;

        console.log(resultado);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Dashboard/" + productId + "/Coupons/GenerateTable",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: '{resultado:'+  resultado + '}',
            success: function (result) {

                alert('Concluido');
            }

        });

    };

    //start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
    reader.readAsText(planilha.files[0]);

}
```

**Action C#**

```
public IActionResult GenerateTable(string resultado)
{
   return Json("Concluido");
}
```

Comment: Conseguiu testar?

Comment: Então @LeandroAngelo testei, mas continua com o erro de bad request.

Comment: Agora entendi, você não preparou a sua controller para receber um json

Comment: O que eu deveria receber como parâmetro na Action?

Comment: Veja a edição da resposta, mas não apenas copie e cole. Tente entender o que você está fazendo e o que está acontecendo ;)

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Você está montando um `Json` inválido, o correto seria.

```
{"resultado": "seu texto"}
```

Altera o seu javascript

```
function lerCSV() {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {

        var resultado = reader.result;

        console.log(resultado);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Dashboard/" + productId + "/Coupons/GenerateTable",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: `{"resultado": "${resultado}"}`,
            success: function (result) {

                alert('Concluido');
            }

        });

    };

    //start reading the file. When it is done, calls the onload event defined above.
    reader.readAsText(planilha.files[0]);

}
```

Mas nesse caso você também deveria alterar a sua `Action` e criar uma `ViewModel` para a serialização e desserialização do objeto. E perceba que o retorno da `Controller` também não está trazendo um `JSon` válido...

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GenerateTable([FromBody] GenerateTableRequestViewModel resultado)
{
   return Json("{ \"Status\" : \"Concluido\"}");
}
```

**GenerateTableRequestViewModel**

```
public class GenerateTableRequestViewModel
{
    public string Resultado {get; set;}
}
```